# Regex - to extract text before the last a hyphen/dash

Tags: javascript, regex

```
Example data                         expected output   

sds-rwewr-dddd-cash0-bbb              cash0
rrse-cash1-nonre                      cash1
loan-snk-cash2-ssdd                   cash2
garb-cash3-dfgfd                      cash3
loan-unwan-cash4-something            cash4
```

The common pattern is here, need to extract a few chars before the last hyphen of given string.

```
var regex1= /.*(?=(?:-[^-]*){1}$)/g ;       //output will be "ds-rwewr-dddd-cash0" from "sds-rwewr-dddd-cash0-bbb  "
var regex2 = /\w[^-]*$/g ;       //output will be "cash0" from "ds-rwewr-dddd-cash0"
var res =regex2.exec(regex1.exec(sds-rwewr-dddd-cash0-bbb)) //output will cash0
```

Although above nested regex is working as expected but may not be optimize one. So any help will be appreciated for optimized regex

Comment: i already tried to create few regex and got unwanted output. Even i have checked old question and answer of stackoverflow and found nothing useful for my case.

Comment: Match last hyphen, search for these kind of questions, there are a lot of them. Then you need a basic pattern matching any chars but `-` one or more times. Then combine. Update the question with what you get if it still does not work.

Comment: i was able to solve by using 2 nested regex which seems not efficient ways like:: var regex1= /.*(?=(?:-[^-]*){1}$)/g ;
var regex2 = /\w[^-]*$/g ;
var res =regex2.exec(regex1.exec(ListofhyphenKeywordVariable)). Let me put new question, if someone has better regex suggestion than this one

Comment: it seems, this question is closed or something is wrong. I tried to open incognito mode and my question is not visible instead of showing : Reference - What does this regex mean? link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64335981/regex-to-extract-text-before-the-last-a-hyphen-dash

Comment: Not all regex engines are the same. Please specify your language.

Comment: it's nodejs language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/\w+(?=-[^-]*$)/
```

If the part before the last hyphen can contain chars other than word chars, keep using `\w[^-]*`: `/\w[^-]*(?=-[^-]*$)/`. If you do not need to check the first char of your match, simply use `/[^-]+(?=-[^-]*$)/`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wl5MLE/1).

Details:

- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?=-[^-]*$)` - that must be followed with `-` and then zero or more chars other than `-` till the end of string.

**JavaScript demo**

```js
const texts = ['sds-rwewr-dddd-cash0-bbb','rrse-cash1-nonre','loan-snk-cash2-ssdd','garb-cash3-dfgfd','loan-unwan-cash4-something'];
const regex = /\w+(?=-[^-]*$)/;
for (var text of texts) {
  console.log(text, '=>', text.match(regex)?.[0]);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much,your piece of code is working in my case.